# Question is about a paper "A Block-sorting Lossless Data Compression Algorithm" by M. Burrows and D.J. Wheeler

Tags: algorithms, data-compression, research

In the paper A Block-sorting Lossless Data Compression Algorithm by M. Burrows and D.J. Wheeler [Link](https://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/Compaq-DEC/SRC-RR-124.pdf).
On page number 5. please describe this line

> If the original string $S$ is of the form $Z^p$ for some substring $Z$ and some $p > 1$, then the sequence $T^i[I]$ for $i = 0,...., N - 1$ will also be of the form $Z'^p$ for some subsequence $Z'$.

Comment: What do you want to know about it?  What do you already understand, and what are you confused about?  Do you want to know what it means?  Why it's true?  Please [edit] your question to clarify.  This will help us get you better answers.

Comment: Am sorry if my question is not clear to you but Answer given by "Bulat" is what am confused about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F.e. string "abc" becomes "bca" after BWT. This means that "abcabc" will transform into "bbccaa", i.e. "external repetition" of entire string will lead to "internal repetition" of each char in transformed string.